# How to get an svn external to be checked out to some other location

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I don't know if this is possible but still if someone can help me that would be very helpful.

I have all externals at the top level in my repository and i want one of the externals to be checked out inside the src directory. can this be possible without changing the actual location of the svn external?

or is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Set an `svn:externals` on the `src` directory pointing to the external you wan to pull from? Im not really sure what your asking and i think you might be confusing `respository` with `working-copy`...

Comment: say for example this is my repo structure                                                                                                                         my-proj
----------external-1                                                 
----------external-2                                                 
----------src                                                        but at the time of checkout i want my external-1 to be checked out inside the src.

Comment: external-1, external-2 and src are inside my-proj(top-level) Trying to flatten out my repo and want to keep all the externals at the top-level instead of nested

Comment: can i checkout/export a external to two different sub-dirs????

Answer (score 0):

Yes, externals can be checked out into subdirectories. The constraints are, the final destination directory cannot already exist, and you cannot use ".." in the destination directory. But destination paths like src/extern1 should be fine. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html for details.

Comment: Hey Ben Thanks for your reply. But i still cant figure it out. I have my external already checking out in external-1 folder. Hoe can i also check it out inside src folder at the time i check out the My-proj. Do i have to edit the svn:externals? can you give me an exact command please. will be a great help

Comment: Yes. Edit your svn:externals. You currently have a rule like "^/path/to/extern/trunk@123 external-1". Change that to "^/path/to/extern/trunk@123 src/external-1" and commit. Now it will be placed in the new location when you checkout/update. This is pretty basic stuff in managing externals, it sounds like you should read up on how externals work.